# Empty div (with style: height as percentage) will not display

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive background image of a room and I want the wall to be 2/3 of the vertical height and the carpet area to be 1/3 of the vertical height.

The following are **pieces** of the code I'm using - my problem is that I want to **percentage control** the heights of the divs instead of assigning pixel values

```
<style>

#room {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#wall_bg_1 {
    background-image:url(./walls/wall_1.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:66%;
    display:block;
}

#carpet_bg_1 {
    background-image:url(.carpets/carpet_1.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:66%;
    display:block;
}
</style>


<body>
        <div id="room">
            <div id="wall_bg_1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="carpet_bg_1">&nbsp;</div>         
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to percentage control the div heights?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to set the height of the main container and also Pay attention to the % of the  #carpet_bg_1 as it should be 33% i believe.

Comment: Code you provided works just fine for me even without any styles for body or html element. Just fix height in #carpet_bg_1 style to 33% as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


#room {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#wall_bg_1 {
    background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/30x30);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:66%;
    display:block;
}

#carpet_bg_1 {
    background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/10x10);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:33%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="room">
            <div id="wall_bg_1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="carpet_bg_1">&nbsp;</div>         
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```